# NumPad keys dont work

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-9.10

I had this problem on the virtual box virtual machine running Ubuntu, that some times, the numpad keys worked and some times they didn't. I thought it was some bug, or some issue with the guest additions, or even that it was related to starting the virtual machine while the numpad led is activated.

Nothing like that.
I though I could share the solution.

Comment: This should of been asked on SuperUser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is quite simple:

System -> Preferences -> Keyboard -> Tab "Mouse Key" -> deactivate "Pointer can be controlled using the keypad".

And the numpad keys work fine.

Source:
https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=18023#p77983

Comment: SO is meant for question relating to programming. By answer these question you're encouraging them to be asked where they shouldn't be.

Comment: Only just realised you answered your own question straight away. Next time try researching the answer prior to asking the question.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I created the question and answered it because SO allows that when you create a new question. In fact, it encourages people to do so, as a "share your knowledge" king of thing...
As for SO being about programming, you're right I did not ponder about that. Although I use the VM to do programing work so its kind of related. :)
As for the "search before you post" argument, I did search and did not found an answer on SO, so I posted it.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem raised when i was using **Ubuntu 15.10** in my laptop.

Can be simply solved by switching off this option(mouse key).

**num keypad not working ubuntu 15.10:**

[image]

Hope this helps in virtual machine too.

Comment: yes, this is the same configuration I have mentioned (adapted for ubuntu 15.10). With a print screen it becomes easier to read :D thanks

Answer (score -1):

Open the soft keyboard in the virtual machine and turn off the num lock, and now numpad  of the physical keyboard can be used